# Vue / Apollo: how to update on new subscription message?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions, vue-apollo

I've been trying to get Vue + Apollo to work with my GraphQL server, it works like a charm except for the subscriptions part.

I'm using

```
apollo: {
  foo: {
    query: ...,
    subscribeToMore: {
      document: ...,
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
         ...
      }
```

as shown in the examples (like [here](https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/8-subscriptions/)).
The new `subscriptionData` arrives but I can't figure out how to merge it with the components `data.foo`.

All the examples use `previous.foo` but my `previous` is `{Symbol(id): "ROOT_QUERY"}`.
Seems like I'm missing a probably simple but crucial piece of understanding here.

How do I get the new `subscriptionData` into the components data object to access it in the template?

**SOLUTION**
Turns out the problem was that the first subscription returns before the initial query result is available in the cache.
Checking `previous` as the `ROOT_QUERY` element for the existence of data solved the problem.
Apollo-Devtools helped a lot here to better understand the data structure in the cache, too.

Comment: I have never used Apollo with Vue.js but maybe I can help you debugging: Have you installed the Apollo Devtools? Does your subscription data end up in the store? This way you can find out if the problem is about updating the store or the component

Comment: @Herku I wasn't aware of the Apollo-Devtools yet, thanks for the tip! I managed to find the problem and solve it, will update the question with the solution. Thanks!